# Can ElasticSearch return elements of an array of a single document?

Tags: elasticsearch

With a document like:

```
{
    "obj1" : [
        {
            "name" : "blue",
            "count" : 4
        },
        {
            "name" : "green",
            "count" : 6
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to query for a `obj1.name = "blue"` to obtain the matching element of the array, not the document?:

```
{
    "name" : "blue",
    "count" : 4
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer is correct below regarding not possible. However, there might be another way to achieve your end goal if you would clarify.

Comment: Hi J.T., basically I want to obtain the values of an array, or for example, the position in the array that match the query. Of course, the array is one more in the doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is not possible now. But there is open [issue](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/3022) for returning nested inner objects.

Comment: Yes, is not possible... I hope they implement.